# Forcing two tables to be at the top of the page on facing pages

Tags: tables, floats, double-sided

The person at the desk next to me is writing his Ph.D. thesis, and is trying to decide how to lay out some tables. He has too much data for one table, but is not a fan of rotated tables. So we were talking and had the idea that he could make two tables, and place them on adjacent pages so you could see them at once. However, you'd have to make sure they didn't wind up on the front/back of a single page.

Is there a way to do that, or is this sheer madness?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from what you say, you may find the `dpfloat` package is your friend.

(note that this expects to live on the two sides of an even-odd page spread.)

see also [faq answer covering the issue](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-dpfloat).

Comment: the description in the question sounds like the referenced table data may not fill two full pages, but it would be good if an equal amount of data were on each page.  the faq entry doesn't appear to address that possibility, nor does the (one-page) package documentation (`texdoc dpfloat`).  on the other hand, the even-odd page arrangement is observed, so maybe some adjustment is possible although it's not obvious from the documentation; i haven't looked at the code.